# Is the average number of steps of a $n$-state $k$-symbol Turing uncomputable?

Tags: computational-complexity, turing-machines

There are finitely many $n$-state and $k$-symbol Turing machines. Call the number $N(n,k)= (2k(n + 1))^{kn}$ (according to Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver). Each of them either halts or does not halt.

Thus, we can speak of a (uniformly) random  $n$-state and $k$-symbol Turing machine that halts.
Let $A(n,k)$ denote the average average number of steps such a machine runs before halting.
Is $A(n,k)$ computable?

The maximum number of steps $M(n,k)$ that such a machine takes is uncomputable and larger than any computable function.

In particular, is the following argument true:
It holds that $A(n,k) \geq \frac{M(n,k)}{N(n,k)}$ and if $A(n,k)$ was computable then $A(n,k)N(n,k)$ would be a computable function larger than $M(n,k)$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: I don't think the last argument holds, since $N(n, k)$ is *also* uncomputable (since if it were computable then you could just run all the relevant Turing machines and wait until $N$ of them halt, and that would give you the value of $M(n, k)$. So the fact that $AN \geq M$ is not enough to show that $A$ is uncomputable. Which doesn't mean it's false, but you need to take a slightly different approach to prove it.

Comment: Well, $N(n,k)$ is the number of $n$-state $k$-symbol Turing machines, not the number of halting $n$-state $k$-symbol Turing machines and that is computable since we have the formula stated.